# th:selected a number in a select/option with Thymeleaf doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have this code

```
<div th:class="form-group">
    <td><label class="control-label leftMargin10 rightMargin10" scope="col" th:text="#{insertHours.hhFrom}">Attivita'</label></td>
    <td><select class="form-control" th:field="*{hhFrom}">
        <option th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(0, 23)}" th:value="${i}" th:text="${i}" th:selected="${ i==9 } ">Options</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</div>
```

When I try to add a condition in th:selected it doesn't work.

I have also replaced with this code:

```
th:attr="${i==9}? selected=selected: '' "
```

but the result is the same.

The HTML

```
<select class="form-control" id="hhFrom" name="hhFrom">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance to answers

Comment: What does the produced HTML look like?

Comment: Try removing `th:field` from `select` and replacing it with some name for testing purposes, and let me know what happens

Comment: @geoand it works with name and id, thanks but why this?

Comment: So it works fine when you use the id? The ninth value is selected? If so I will add it as answer for future viewers

Comment: I added the answer along with a link to more information that will help you figure out why what you posted doesn't work

Comment: @geoand yes it work when I use id and name with number nine selected thanks again!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You cannot use `th:field` along with `th:selected`.
If you replace `th:field` with `name=someMeaningfullName` the code will work just fine.

Check out [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20200721151501/http://forum.thymeleaf.org/th-selected-not-working-on-multiple-select-td4025883.html) thread on the Thymeleaf forum for more information

Comment: forum link does not appear to work

Answer (score 9):

Another hack that, is pretty simple and **works**, is to close the select tag: `<select ... />`

Please note `/>` at the end of first line:

```
<select th:field="*{percentage}" />
    <option th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(0, 100)}" th:value="${i}" th:text="${i}" th:selected="${i==75}"></option>
</select>
```

Renders as:

```
<select id="percentage" name="percentage" />
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    ...
    <option value="74">74</option>
    <option value="75" selected="selected">75</option>
    <option value="76">76</option>
    ...
    <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

Both web browser and Thymeleaf will handle this fine.

I used Thymeleaf v.`3.0.9.RELEASE`

Answer (score 5):

Also I found out that if you put `<div>` tag around option fields, selected="selected" will also work. e.g

```
<select th:field="*{name}">
    <div>
        <option disabled="true" selected="selected" value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">first</option>
        <option value="2">second</option>
    </div>
</select>
```