# PreSelect Value from Dropdown

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I was able to populate my dropdown, however I cannot preselect the value of the dropdown base on the value coming from DB.

My Thymeleaf

```
   <select id="inputstatus" name="status" th:field="*{status}" >            
      <option th:each="enumStatus : ${listStatus}"    
           th:value="${enumStatus.code}" 
           th:text="#{${enumStatus.value}}" />
    </select>
```

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "userdetails/{username}")
public String getAccounts(@PathVariable String username, Model model) {
    Account accountDetail = rsAccountDetailsService.loadAccountByUserName(username);
    model.addAttribute(ACCNTSEARCH_MODEL_ACCNTSTATUS_KEY, AccountDetailsStatus.values());
    model.addAttribute("userdetailform",accountDetail);


    return "account/userdetails";

}
```

My ENUM

```
public enum AccountDetailsStatus {
ACTIVE(0, "status.active"),
EXPIRED(2, "status.expired"),
LOCKED(3, "status.locked");

private int code;
private String value;

private final static class BootstrapSingleton {
    public static final Map<String, AccountDetailsStatus> lookupByValue = new HashMap<String, AccountDetailsStatus>();
    public static final Map<Integer, AccountDetailsStatus> lookupByCode = new HashMap<Integer, AccountDetailsStatus>();

}

AccountDetailsStatus(int code, String value) {
    this.code = code;
    this.value = value;
    BootstrapSingleton.lookupByValue.put(value, this);
    BootstrapSingleton.lookupByCode.put(new Integer(code), this);

}

public int getCode() {
    return code;
}


public String getValue() {
    return value;
}
```

}

If the user details were loaded with for example "ACTIVE" status, the active status in the dropdown is not selected.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are looking for something similar  use the th:selected tag

```
<option th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(0, 23)}" th:value="${i}" th:text="${i}" th:selected="${ i==9 } ">Options</option>
```

i linked some similar post here 
http://forum.thymeleaf.org/th-selected-not-working-on-multiple-select-td4025883.html

[th:selected a number in a select/option with Thymeleaf doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203220/thselected-a-number-in-a-select-option-with-thymeleaf-doesnt-work)